# Draw equal paths from the same geographic point

Tags: java, google-maps

I have 10'000 geographic points (POS), 10 salesmen, and one starting point. **The goal is To avoid discrimination between salesmen, everyone should travel the same distance and the same number of points of sale.**

To achieve this, i think i theses rules should be applied:

1. assign a path for each salesman starting from the starting point with the same number of geographic points (POS).
2. Each path should have the same distance.

My solution is sort an array of GPS coordinate points by distance and then assign each point to a path until the end of the loop, but doubt this will work..

What is the easiest algorithm to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: That sounds like a variation of the travelling salesman problem so any suitable algorithm should fit.

Comment: Doesn't sound like there is an easy algorithm.

Comment: Note that it might not be possible to get 10 distinct paths of equal length which have the same number of vertices/points.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem i've found this alghorithm but it's won't solve i guess my problem

Comment: Well there are a _lot_ of algorithms to tackle that problem, some being exact and some heuristic. Why do you think one of those algorithms wouldn't solve your problem? Note that your problem is a variation of the original problem in that you'll need to get 10 routes which should have as similar characteristics as possible so you'll need to adapt the algorithms you've found. Since that kind of problem normally is more a theoretical one (at least the description hints at that) I guess it's part of _your_ task to find a suitable solution - we'll try to help but _you_ need to do the work.

Comment: Note that this is not exactly the traveling salesman problem. One is not trying to find a minimal path. One is trying to divide the 10,000 into 10 lists (order is important as it affects distance) which have the same distance. The search space is huge.

Comment: You might want to add some more rules to your problem to make it more specific. From the graphic I would assume that the path of every salesman should have `unique / distinct` locations. -- Also is the path length really supposed to be the `exact` same distance-wise? I would assume - if that is a real world problem - that there is some acceptable difference between the travel pathes. -- Also its not quite clear how long the path of a salesman must be? Do all the 10.000 locations require a visit or are 10 fixed pathes with the same number of locations acceptable?

Comment: @second Thank you for your comment! yes each path should have unique locations, yes same as possible but the same number of locations  to visit should be the same for every salesman.. each salesman should visit 1000 locations in a month, that's about 38 locations per day (1000pos/26days)

Comment: i've found this, it's pretty close to what i need https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp

Comment: Do they all start from the same point?

Comment: @Edward Aung yes , the same point

Comment: Try some partition algorithm (network partition algorithm). If you can relax the not going to the same nodes restriction a bit, you will have a better chance.

Comment: Share some code in which you tried to achieve it but not......

Comment: 38 locations per day? how does this play a role? That probably means that it matters how fast they are, which in turn will probably tell us something about the distances they have to travel and can narrow down the possibilities. More information needed.
If there are not paths between the locations then the salespeople can basically jump from any one location to another and their paths could also cross even if the locations don't overlap and the result will not look like a start as you depicted it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very good starting point of ordering the points by distance from the start. Now consider the 10,000 points as 1000 concentric rings of 10 points each. All we have to do is assign one point from every ring to a salesman as follows:

- order the salesmen by path length of their current points
- starting with the salesman with the longest path:

  - let the salesman take the point (of 10 in current ring) that is closest
  - continue for the next salesman (of 9 remaining points in current ring)
  - and so on for the other 8 salesmen

If you iterate the rings from outer to inner, the differences in path lengths will get smaller (as opposed to going from small rings to larger).

You can seed each salesman with each point from the outermost ring.

For the 'closest' step, you can just connect the last added point to the currently point being considered for adding. The paths won't be the shortest for each salesman's set of points, but each will have the same inefficiency and overall the path length differences will converge toward zero.

If you want to improve each salesman's path, when considering adding a point, you can find the two closest points in the 'in set' to the candidate and insert it between them, or append it to one of the 'end' points if that distance is shorter than the sum of distances to the two closest points.